# Mutating variadic arguments

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want a function/define taking variadic argument pack which expands mutating each of the arguments in some pattern, like:

```
foo(1,2,3);
foo(1,2,3,4,5);
```

should expand to

```
bar(modifier_1,modifier_2,modifier_3);
bar(modifier_1,modifier_2,modifier_3,modifier_4,modifier_5);
```

can this be achieved? If so, how?

Comment: See Boost Preprocessor — but consider whether what you're doing is sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using boost preprocessor you could do something like this:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/size.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>

#define PREFIX_TUPLE_HELPER(z,n,data) \
   BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0,data),\
                BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(n,BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1,data)))

#define PREFIX_TUPLE(PREFIX_,TUPLE_) BOOST_PP_ENUM \
   ( BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE(TUPLE_), \
     PREFIX_TUPLE_HELPER, \
     (PREFIX_,TUPLE_))

#define foo(...) bar(PREFIX_TUPLE(modifier_,(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

[Online demo here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3941ceb31be01f3)

There's not much to explain.  `PREFIX_TUPLE` uses [`BOOST_PP_ENUM`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/enum.html) to produce the comma delimited list.  The helper macro just needs the data to do the work; to that end, we just give it a two-[tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/data/tuples.html) of the prefix and the tuple of elements to paste to.